# How to simplify callback code in Node.js using async.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I am using MEAN technologies for my project. In Node.js we need to use `callbacks`. Here I have a function which updates user entry in the database. Before storing into the database I need to first validate the data then performs some checks. By doing this my code is going to be very complex. I heard about [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

Can someone suggest me how I can reduce the complexity of this code? I don't know much about async but can it really solve my problem?.

I also have to perform some other checks like authorization. And I don't want to write a callback hell.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

```
    function updateUser(user_id, userData, cb){
      let response = {};

      //validate user data
      validate(userData, function(isPassed, validationResult){
        if(isPassed){
          //validate user id
          validateUserId(user_id, function(isValid){
            if(isValid){
              db.findById({ _id: user_id}, function(err, user){
                if(err){
                  response.status = 'error';
                  response.data = err;
                  cb(response);
                } else {
                  user.save(userData, function(err, numOfRow){
                    if(err){
                      response.status = 'error';
                      response.data = err;
                      cb(response);
                    } else {
                      response.status = 'success';
                      response.data = numOfRow;
                      cb(response);
                    }
                  })
                }
              })
            } else {
              response.status = 'error';
              response.data = 'Provided id is not valid';
              cb(response);
            }
          });
        } else {
          response.status = 'validationError';
          response.data = validationResult;
          cb(response);
        }
      });

    }

    function validate(data, cb){
      // checks some conditions here
      cb(false, [errors]);
    }

    function validateUserId(id, cb){
      // checks some conditions here
      cb(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a blog post which solves my problem https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/ I hope it will also help others.

Thanks.